# NFS single mount point with symlinks vs multiple mount points

Tags: linux, networking, nfs

I currently have 3 servers: file, web, and computational. I want to have a folder in every person's home folded shared between the systems. The NFS server is working but was wondering if it would be better to mount every user's shared folder separately or to mount all the shared folder in one location and symlink the individual folders to this location.

Ex.
mount FS_name:/path/to/users/shared/folder /home/username/shared/ ( for each user )

or

mount FS_name:/path/to/all/shared/folders /mnt/shared/
ln -s /mnt/shared/username /home/username/shared

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinks are easier to keep updated than mount points. Another solution is to simply mount /home from NFS. To keep user ids try NIS (for a small network of trusted users is ok). If you want something more secure go for LDAP or Kerberos.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion the NIS with shared home folders is almost exactly what I need.